# azcopy: failed to parse user input due to error: the inferred source/destination combination is currently not supported

Tags: python, azure, blob, azcopy

I am currently working on a program where when I run it, it will do a blob data transfer from my VM to my azure storage using SAS. The code I have written so far is this:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
try:
    key = input("Please insert SAS: ")
    #file_path = input("Please insert the full file path where the data is located: ")
    full_link = ("\"https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/" + key + "\"")
    #print('\n File path: '+ full_link +'\n')
#Subprocess that performs data transfer to storage from the desired path
    subprocess.call(['azcopy', 'cp', '/directory/subdirectory', 
                    full_link,
                    '--recursive=true'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print('Transfer Complete.')

#Exception for exit error
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
     raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))

#Exception for EOF error, would be caused by missing token
except EOFError as error:
    print('Error with token')

#When an unexpected error has occured.
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e) + 'Unknown error has occured')
exit(0)
```

When I run this I receive the following error:

```
failed to parse user input due to error: the inferred source/destination combination is currently not supported.
```

I am unsure as to what the issue is because when I run the actual command in the terminal and it does the data copy that I wanted. The command is below:

```
sudo ./azcopy cp "/directory/subdirectory" "https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/darknet-index[SAS]" --recursive=true
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing **blob container name** in the full link.

Here is my code running on windows, you can change it to run on linux:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
try:
    #sas token
    key = '?sv=2019-02-02&xx'

    #define the container name in blob storage
    mycontainer = "test6"
    exepath = "F:\\azcopy\\latest\\azcopy.exe"
    local_directory="F:\\temp\\1\\test2\\*"
    endpoint="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/"+mycontainer

    myscript=exepath + " cp " + "\""+ local_directory + "\" " + "\""+endpoint + key + "\"" + " --recursive"

    print(myscript)
    subprocess.call(myscript)

    print('Transfer Complete.')

#Exception for exit error
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
     raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))

#Exception for EOF error, would be caused by missing token
except EOFError as error:
    print('Error with token')

#When an unexpected error has occured.
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e) + 'Unknown error has occured')
exit(0)
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not fix it, however, I submitted a ticket to Microsoft support and your recommendation helped me clean my code. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Buzzkillionair, ok, please share with us the root cause if any feedback from ms support:).

Comment: Will do when I hear back.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft was unable to help and neither was the azcopy git. Sorry that I cant find an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can't resolve /directory/subdirectory to a real disk location, due to the working directory being different when you run it from within your Python app.

Comment: If I run the command I provide from the same location as the python command it works, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Which version of AzCopy do you have?

Comment: You can see the version by running `azcopy version`

Comment: I am on version 10.3.2

Comment: I don't know what the problem could be, I'm sorry.

Comment: No worries at all!